# MKMapView does not set region or add annotations when caller is from push notification(?)

Tags: ios, push-notification, mkmapview

I have two identical code segments that each define a region of a map (setRegion) and sets an annotation pin within the map (addAnnotation).  The only difference is that one segment is invoked as a result of a user interaction with a button on the screen while the other segment is invoked as a response to an incoming push notification (through didReceiveRemoteNotification).

The user interaction invoked one works as expected but the push notification invoked one does not (it shows the map but does not define the region or add the annotation pin).

Is there something that needs to be done to properly initialize the MKMapView if it is invoked from a push notification?  Both routines are defined in the AppDelegate.m file although they are referring to a MapView in a UIViewController.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

    // This routine is invoked when a push notification is received by the app
    // The map is shown but the annotation and region are ignored by the map

    MapPin *one = [[MapPin alloc] init];
    one.title = @"";
    one.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, long);
    [mapView1 addAnnotation:one];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D zoomLocation;
    zoomLocation.latitude = lastLatitude;
    zoomLocation.longitude = lastLongitude;
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(zoomLocation, 50, 50);
    [mapView1 setRegion:region animated:YES]; 
 }


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alert clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    // This routine is invoked when the user taps on a button in an alert
    // Everything works ok (i.e., annotation shows up and region is properly defined)

    MapPin *two = [[MapPin alloc] init];
    two.title = @"";
    two.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, long);
    [mapView2 addAnnotation:two];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D zoomLocation;
    zoomLocation.latitude = lastLatitude;
    zoomLocation.longitude = lastLongitude;
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(zoomLocation, 50, 50);
    [mapView2 setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: please include the code you have, what you have done and what do you expect

Comment: I just added in the code segments with comments